# Android - App crashes on Pre-Lollipop devices

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-support-library, fatal-error, android-recyclerview

My app crashes on some of the pre-lollipop devices.  I recently implemented recyclerView. Not sure if it has to do anything with that.  This is what i get in the logcat.

```
I/DEBUG   (  272): pid: 18489, tid: 18913, name: DataRequestDisp  >>> com.mypackage <<<
    W/ActivityManager(  811):   Force finishing activity com.mypackage/.activities.MainActivity
    V/SmartFaceService - 3rd party pause(  811): onReceive [android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_STATE/com.mypackage/pause]
    D/CrashAnrDetector(  811): pid: 18489, tid: 18913, name: DataRequestDisp  >>> com.mypackage <<<
    D/CrashAnrDetector(  811): processName:com.mypackage
    D/CrashAnrDetector(  811): broadcastEvent : com.mypackage SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE
    I/ActivityManager(  811): Process com.mypackage (pid 18489) (adj 9) has died.
    I/WindowState(  811): WIN DEATH: Window{42a4cbd8 u0 com.mypackage/com.mypackage.activities.MainActivity}
    I/WindowState(  811): WIN DEATH: Window{43223d50 u0 com.mypackage/com.mypackage.activities.Alert}
```

**Edit**
Here is a more detailed logcat

```
02-24 22:10:43.903 I/DEBUG   (  272): !@dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_native -m 24479
02-24 22:10:43.903 W/ActivityManager(  811):   Force finishing activity com.mypackage/.activities.MainActivity
02-24 22:10:43.913 I/dumpstate(24698): begin
02-24 22:10:43.913 I/BootReceiver(  811): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_08 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
02-24 22:10:43.953 D/InputReader(  811): Input event: value=1 when=8959982975000
02-24 22:10:43.953 I/InputReader(  811): Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.259 ] when=8959983036000
02-24 22:10:43.953 D/InputDispatcher(  811): Waiting for application to become ready for input: xxxx Reason: Waiting because the touched window is paused.
02-24 22:10:44.053 D/InputReader(  811): Input event: value=0 when=8960086033000
02-24 22:10:44.053 I/InputReader(  811): Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=] when=8960086033000
02-24 22:10:44.103 D/dalvikvm(  811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3194K, 28% free 59120K/81588K, paused 165ms, total 167ms
02-24 22:10:44.113 W/ContextImpl(  811): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:-1 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked:-1 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked:-1 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked:-1 com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked:-1 
02-24 22:10:44.123 V/SmartFaceService - 3rd party pause(  811): onReceive [android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_STATE/com.mypackage/pause]
02-24 22:10:44.133 W/ApplicationPackageManager(  811): getCSCPackageItemText()
02-24 22:10:44.153 E/MP-Decision( 2241): num online cores: 2 reqd : 3 available : 4 rq_depth:6.300000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 126
02-24 22:10:44.153 E/MP-Decision( 2241): UP cpu:1 core_idx:1 Nw:1.900000 Tw:140 rq:6.300000 seq:0.000000
02-24 22:10:44.153 E/MP-Decision( 2241): UP cpu:2 core_idx:2 Nw:2.700000 Tw:90 rq:6.300000 seq:107.000000
02-24 22:10:44.153 I/dumpstate(24705): begin
02-24 22:10:44.153 I/dumpstate(24705): dumpstate is still running
02-24 22:10:44.163 I/SpenGestureManager(  811): setFocusWindow0
02-24 22:10:44.163 D/EnterpriseDeviceManager(  811): ContainerId: 0
02-24 22:10:44.163 D/STATUSBAR-StatusBarManagerService(  811): manageDisableList what=0x0 pkg=WindowManager.LayoutParams
02-24 22:10:44.163 D/RestrictionPolicy(  811): isStatusBarExpansionAllowed : true
02-24 22:10:44.163 I/BootReceiver(  811): Notify a SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE FilePath:tombstone_08
02-24 22:10:44.173 V/WindowOrientationListener(  811): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, mbResultFaceDectection: false
02-24 22:10:44.173 V/WindowOrientationListener(  811): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, Rotation: 0
02-24 22:10:44.173 V/WindowOrientationListener(  811): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, mbResultFaceDectection: false
02-24 22:10:44.173 V/WindowOrientationListener(  811): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, Rotation: 0
02-24 22:10:44.173 D/PointerIcon(  811): setMouseIconStyle1 pointerType: 1001iconType:101 flag:0
02-24 22:10:44.173 D/PointerIcon(  811): setMouseCustomIcon IconType is same.101
02-24 22:10:44.173 D/PointerIcon(  811): setHoveringSpenIconStyle1 pointerType: 10001iconType:1 flag:0
02-24 22:10:44.173 D/PointerIcon(  811): setHoveringSpenCustomIcon IconType is same.1
02-24 22:10:44.173 W/ContextImpl(  811): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:-1 android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast:-1 android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast:-1 com.android.server.BootReceiver$2.onEvent:-1 android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.onEvent:-1 
02-24 22:10:44.173 V/WindowManager(  811): rotationForOrientationLw(orient=-1, last=0); user=0 USER_ROTATION_LOCKED sensorRotation=0 mLidState=-1 mDockMode=0 mHdmiPlugged=false mAccelerometerDefault=false gripRotationLock=false
02-24 22:10:44.173 I/SurfaceFlinger(  282): id=125 createSurf (1x1),1 flag=4, iorizontal
02-24 22:10:44.193 I/InputDispatcher(  811): Delivering touch to: action: 0x4
02-24 22:10:44.193 I/InputDispatcher(  811): Delivering touch to: action: 0x0
02-24 22:10:44.193 I/InputDispatcher(  811): Delivering touch to: action: 0x1
02-24 22:10:44.203 E/MP-Decision( 2241): num online cores: 3 reqd : 4 available : 4 rq_depth:4.700000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 205
02-24 22:10:44.203 E/MP-Decision( 2241): UP cpu:1 core_idx:1 Nw:1.900000 Tw:140 rq:4.700000 seq:0.000000
02-24 22:10:44.203 E/MP-Decision( 2241): UP cpu:2 core_idx:2 Nw:2.700000 Tw:90 rq:4.700000 seq:0.000000
02-24 22:10:44.203 E/MP-Decision( 2241): UP cpu:3 core_idx:3 Nw:3.500000 Tw:90 rq:4.700000 seq:105.000000
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811): Build: samsung/jfltespr/jfltespr:4.4.2/KOT49H/I9500XXUFNB7:user/release-keys
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811): Hardware: MSM8960
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811): Revision: 11
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811): Bootloader: L720VPUFNAE
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811): Radio: unknown
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811): Kernel: Linux version 3.4.0-481102 (dpi@SWDD5908) (gcc version 4.7 (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jan 28 22:01:56 KST 2014
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811): 
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/jfltespr/jfltespr:4.4.2/KOT49H/I9500XXUFNB7:user/release-keys'
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811): Revision: '11'
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811): pid: 24479, tid: 24568, name: pool-12-thread-  >>> com.mypackage <<<
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     r0 00000001  r1 7b29b99b  r2 0000000f  r3 ffffffff
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     r4 00000000  r5 00000000  r6 7b7d8965  r7 00000000
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     r8 7b7d8965  r9 7b7d8965  sl 00000029  fp 7b7d8966
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     ip 7307bad0  sp 7b29b920  lr 7306e869  pc 40c05de4  cpsr 000f0030
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     d4  0000000000000001  d5  0000000000000007
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     d6  0000000000000008  d7  0000040000000009
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     d16 b01a01036a000002  d17 18144eea590b954f
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     d18 4ceb6420c7468e2c  d19 2c13ed20f88cfa43
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     d20 c0006abe464e18bd  d21 0000000042000007
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     d22 000b0000010001ff  d23 0023000201000304
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     d28 0100010001000100  d29 0100010001000100
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     scr 60000010
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811): 
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811): backtrace:
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     #00  pc 00023de4  /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_select_next_proto+25)
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     #01  pc 00008865  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     #02  pc 0002ab65  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl_parse_serverhello_tlsext+468)
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     #03  pc 00016bbd  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl3_get_server_hello+904)
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     #04  pc 000196bf  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl3_connect+642)
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     #05  pc 00025015  /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_connect+18)
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     #06  pc 00011aad  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl23_connect+2040)
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     #07  pc 00024f55  /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_do_handshake+72)
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     #08  pc 0000c67f  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     #09  pc 00020bcc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     #10  pc 00051927  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     #11  pc 0002a060  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     #12  pc 00031510  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     #13  pc 0002eba8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     #14  pc 00063e75  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     #15  pc 00063e99  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     #16  pc 00058b6b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     #17  pc 0000d280  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     #18  pc 0000d418  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811): 
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811): stack:
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b8e0  00000000  
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b8e4  7225c580  
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b8e8  7306e7a1  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b8ec  7225a568  
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b8f0  00000145  
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b8f4  40a443c3  /system/lib/libcrypto.so (CRYPTO_lock+78)
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b8f8  40ad36bd  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b8fc  7225a568  
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b900  00000003  
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b904  00000000  
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b908  401471c8  
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b90c  00000000  
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b910  7bf9dcc8  
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b914  4010a01b  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+4254)
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b918  df002777  
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b91c  e3a070ad  
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):     #00  7b29b920  40108f7d  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc)
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b924  7b29b99b  [stack:24568]
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b928  00000000  
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b92c  7b29b99c  [stack:24568]
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b930  40c1529a  /system/lib/libssl.so
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b934  7b7d8965  
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b938  7d6bf018  
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b93c  7b29b99b  [stack:24568]
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b940  7b29b99c  [stack:24568]
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b944  7b82c878  
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b948  7b7d8965  
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811):          7b29b94c  00000001
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811): processName:com.mypackage
02-24 22:10:44.223 D/CrashAnrDetector(  811): broadcastEvent : com.mypackage SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE
02-24 22:10:44.223 W/ContextImpl(  811): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:-1 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector.broadcastEvent:-1 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector.processDropBoxEntry:-1 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector.access$100:-1 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector$1.onReceive:-1 
02-24 22:10:44.243 W/qdhwcomposer(  282): Excessive delay reading vsync: took 1362 ms
02-24 22:10:44.373 D/dalvikvm(11262): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2059K, 29% free 19059K/26780K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 29ms
02-24 22:10:44.373 D/dalvikvm(11262): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 25ms

02-24 22:10:44.403 W/qdhwcomposer(  282): Excessive delay reading vsync: took 116 ms
02-24 22:10:44.443 E/android.os.Debug(  811): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
02-24 22:10:44.453 E/MP-Decision( 2241): num online cores: 4 reqd : 3 available : 4 rq_depth:0.500000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 97
02-24 22:10:44.453 E/MP-Decision( 2241): DOWN cpu:3 core_idx:3 Ns:3.100000 Ts:240 rq:0.500000 seq:243.000000
02-24 22:10:44.453 I/dumpstate(24717): begin
02-24 22:10:44.453 I/dumpstate(24717): dumpstate is still running
02-24 22:10:44.503 E/MP-Decision( 2241): num online cores: 3 reqd : 2 available : 4 rq_depth:1.200000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 45
02-24 22:10:44.503 E/MP-Decision( 2241): DOWN cpu:2 core_idx:2 Ns:2.100000 Ts:240 rq:1.200000 seq:242.000000
02-24 22:10:44.553 E/MP-Decision( 2241): num online cores: 2 reqd : 1 available : 4 rq_depth:0.100000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 14
02-24 22:10:44.553 E/MP-Decision( 2241): DOWN cpu:1 core_idx:1 Ns:1.100000 Ts:190 rq:0.100000 seq:43.000000

02-24 22:10:44.633 D/SSRMv2:CustomFrequencyManagerService(  811): acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1350000  uid : 1000  pid : 811  pkgName : ACTIVITY_RESUME_BOOSTER@6
02-24 22:10:44.633 W/ActivityManager(  811): mDVFSHelper.acquire()
02-24 22:10:44.643 D/SurfaceWidgetView( 1367): destroyHardwareResources():1120326816
02-24 22:10:44.643 D/SurfaceWidgetView( 1367): destroyHardwareResources():1124498920
02-24 22:10:44.643 V/WindowOrientationListener(  811): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, mbResultFaceDectection: false
02-24 22:10:44.643 V/WindowOrientationListener(  811): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, Rotation: 0
02-24 22:10:44.643 V/WindowOrientationListener(  811): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, mbResultFaceDectection: false
02-24 22:10:44.643 V/WindowOrientationListener(  811): mSContextAutoRotationListener.getProposedRotation, Rotation: 0
02-24 22:10:44.643 V/WindowManager(  811): rotationForOrientationLw(orient=1, last=0); user=0 USER_ROTATION_LOCKED sensorRotation=0 mLidState=-1 mDockMode=0 mHdmiPlugged=false mAccelerometerDefault=false gripRotationLock=false
02-24 22:10:44.663 D/Launcher( 1367): onRestart, Launcher: 1117486472
02-24 22:10:44.663 D/Launcher( 1367): onStart, Launcher: 1117486472
02-24 22:10:44.663 D/Launcher.HomeView( 1367): onStart
02-24 22:10:44.663 D/Launcher( 1367): onResume, Launcher: 1117486472
02-24 22:10:44.663 D/Launcher.HomeView( 1367): onResume
02-24 22:10:44.663 W/ContextImpl(  811): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:-1 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityLocked:-1 com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.resumeTopActivitiesLocked:-1 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.completePauseLocked:-1 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.activityPausedLocked:-1 
02-24 22:10:44.673 D/MenuAppsGridFragment( 1367): onResume
02-24 22:10:44.673 D/SurfaceWidgetClient$ISurfaceWidgetStub( 1856): [123491/1] Surface widget visibility changed visibility = true on instance = 1
02-24 22:10:44.673 D/SurfaceWidgetClient$ISurfaceWidgetStub( 1873): [123491/1] Surface widget visibility changed visibility = true on instance = 1
02-24 22:10:44.683 D/SurfaceWidget.Renderer( 1856): [123491/1] SurfaceWidgetRenderer waiting done: 1 (Thread[Thread-121,5,main])
02-24 22:10:44.683 D/SurfaceWidget.Renderer( 1856): [123491/1] SurfaceWidget drawing first frame
02-24 22:10:44.683 D/SurfaceWidget.Renderer( 1873): [123491/1] SurfaceWidgetRenderer waiting done: 1 (Thread[Thread-123,5,main])
02-24 22:10:44.683 D/SurfaceWidget.Renderer( 1856): [123491/1] SurfaceWidgetRenderer waiting: 1 (Thread[Thread-121,5,main])
02-24 22:10:44.683 D/SurfaceWidget.Renderer( 1873): [123491/1] SurfaceWidget drawing first frame
02-24 22:10:44.683 I/SurfaceFlinger(  282): id=126 createSurf (1080x1920),1 flag=4, Mauncher
02-24 22:10:44.704 D/SurfaceWidget.Renderer( 1873): [123491/1] SurfaceWidgetRenderer waiting: 1 (Thread[Thread-123,5,main])
02-24 22:10:44.754 E/MP-Decision( 2241): num online cores: 1 reqd : 4 available : 4 rq_depth:4.700000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 49
02-24 22:10:44.754 E/MP-Decision( 2241): UP cpu:1 core_idx:1 Nw:1.900000 Tw:140 rq:4.700000 seq:144.000000
02-24 22:10:44.754 E/MP-Decision( 2241): UP cpu:2 core_idx:2 Nw:2.700000 Tw:90 rq:4.700000 seq:98.000000
02-24 22:10:44.754 E/MP-Decision( 2241): UP cpu:3 core_idx:3 Nw:3.500000 Tw:90 rq:4.700000 seq:98.000000
02-24 22:10:44.754 V/SmartFaceService - 3rd party pause(  811): onReceive [android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_STATE/com.sec.android.app.launcher/resume]
02-24 22:10:44.764 I/ActivityManager(  811): RTCC_TRIGGER_MSG, ASYNC.
02-24 22:10:44.774 D/FavoriteProvider(20389): onReceive(), com.sec.android.intent.action.HOME_RESUME
02-24 22:10:44.784 D/EnterpriseDeviceManager(  811): ContainerId: 0
02-24 22:10:44.784 D/STATUSBAR-StatusBarManagerService(  811): manageDisableList what=0x0 pkg=WindowManager.LayoutParams
02-24 22:10:44.784 D/RestrictionPolicy(  811): isStatusBarExpansionAllowed : true
02-24 22:10:44.794 D/Mms/UIEventReceiver( 7019): ui event
02-24 22:10:44.824 V/TaskCloserActivity(10421): TaskCloserActivity onReceive() - com.sec.android.intent.action.HOME_RESUME
02-24 22:10:45.054 E/MP-Decision( 2241): num online cores: 4 reqd : 2 available : 4 rq_depth:0.900000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 96
02-24 22:10:45.054 E/MP-Decision( 2241): DOWN cpu:3 core_idx:3 Ns:3.100000 Ts:240 rq:0.900000 seq:245.000000
02-24 22:10:45.054 E/MP-Decision( 2241): DOWN cpu:2 core_idx:2 Ns:2.100000 Ts:240 rq:0.900000 seq:245.000000
02-24 22:10:45.134 D/SSRMv2:CustomFrequencyManagerService(  811): releaseDVFSLockLocked : Getting Lock type frm List : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1350000  uid : 1000  pid : 811  tag : ACTIVITY_RESUME_BOOSTER@6
02-24 22:10:45.134 W/ActivityManager(  811): mDVFSHelper.release()
02-24 22:10:45.134 D/SSRMv2:CustomFrequencyManagerService(  811): acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1350000  uid : 1000  pid : 811  pkgName : ACTIVITY_RESUME_BOOSTER@9
02-24 22:10:45.174 W/EDMNativeHelper(  270): EDMNativeHelperService is published
```

Comment: Does this happen when you receive a broadcast ? Can you post the which executes before the crash ?

Comment: No there is no broadcast. I just display a list of objects using recyclerview. It works fine on lolipop devices and some of the pre-lolipop as well

Comment: Are you using a native library ?

Comment: Can you post your code `block`

Comment: This seems like the "death notification".  Are you sure there's not a stack framer earlier in the logcat?

Comment: Nothing else. In the android studio i just get Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), thread 29117 (pool-16-thread-) . I tried the cmd logcat and got the above stacktrace. before that its all normal stuff

Comment: @Shivam Verma what do you mean by native library ?

Comment: @sayed c, c++ code, a .so library ?

Comment: No, i am not using any of those

Comment: @all i have edited my question with a more detailed logcat. May be someone can make sense out of it

Comment: @sayed when does it crash? On rotation or while populating list?

Comment: It would crash even without doing anything. Anyways i found the culprit. It was the zendesk mobile sdk that for some reason was making the app crash on some pre-lollipop devices. I have reported it to their developers. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @sayed I was about to link you to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28757478/1276636). Seems like you fixed the problem, right?

Comment: @sufian Thanks for the help. I have enabled multiDex correctly. The problem was caused by one of he libraries (zendesk mobile sdk). I removed it and everything is fine now.